# Refreshing page removes bootstrap-select stylings

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, select

I'm working with bootstrap-select and I'm new to front-end. I'm trying to implement bootstrap's multi-select component in my page but the problem 
I'm facing is that, when I submit my page to server and if error occurs, it removes all the css classes from select box and simply shows a multi-select list instead of the original component. 
The component I'm using is [This](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) and following is my jsp code where I'm trying to use this component.

```
<spring:bind path="userClients">
   <div id="customerSelect" class="${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}" style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:15px height:30px">
       <form:select  class="selectpicker form-control"  path="userClients" multiple="multiple" name="userClients">
            <c:forEach var="clientInfo" items="${clients}">
               <form:option value="${clientInfo.env}">${clientInfo.env}</form:option>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
        <div class="${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <form:errors  path="userClients" ></form:errors>
        </div>
   </div>
   </spring:bind>
```

Following is my pageOnLoad chunk of code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('select').selectpicker();
 });
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think on refresh, the css classes are removed from the component hence making it a simple multi-select list. Try adding an id to select component e.g. id="select-picker" and then force render with the reference of this id like following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select-picker').selectpicker('render');
}
```

Or if you are submitting the form then make sure you call this render function inside of submit function too to ensure re-rendering of the component properly.

Comment: Welcome @NyleHassan :)