# React.js & backend on App Engine as services?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine

I am deploying a React.js front-end (built with create-react-app) and a back-end with a CRUD API that connects to Cloud SQL.

Is this a good way?

- React.js front-end is a **default** service.
- Back-end API is **backend** service

I'm familiar with deploying to Heroku, which had front-end and back-end on different ports. Would that work for App Engine?

This is all in Node.js.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any issues with the described design.

To get you on track you can take a look in Stack Overflow thread [How to deploy create-react-app to Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245355/how-to-deploy-create-react-app-to-google-cloud?rq=1) or the following [tutorial](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/deploying-react-app-to-google-app-engine-a6ea0d5af132).

You can run applications on different ports with  setting [port forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#port_forwarding) in your `app.yaml` file.

Comment: If I make an AJAX call from react to the backend service, would I need to use the absolute URL? Like this: `https://service-dot-project-id-appspot.com/api/request`

Answer (score 1):

The design pattern is good.

You only need to create a `dispatch.yaml` file which is only one per project.

Your dispatch.yaml file would look something like this:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/backend/*"
    service: backend
```

Then your frontend at project-id.appspot.com will simply make requests to https:/project-id.appspot.com/backend/ *, and these requests will be redirected to the API service.