# Page not found issue when directly visit the link in svelte-routing

Tags: routes, svelte

I used the `svelte-routing` module for the router in my svelte project.
When I visit the link by clicking navlink in the component then it goes well, but when I visit the link directly by typing it in the browerlink I got the `page not found` error.
For example if I visit `localhost:5000` at first and click the `about` link then the link is changed to `localhost:5000/about` and goes to the `about.svelte` component, but when I input the link in the browser link directly `localhost:5000/about` then it shows `page not found` message.
If this problem happens in the local then I think it will still happen after deployment.
So I want to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is because `localhost:5000/about` does not exist.

When you use the navlink it will actually not go to the location, only change the url but you stay on the same page.

To get this working you will need to redirect everything to `index.html`, basically if a user goes to `yourdomain/about` they *should* go to `yourdomain/index.html` and svelte-routing will take care of showing the correct route.

If you use the default svelte template it uses a package called `sirv` to do the hosting in localhost, in your package.json change the `start` command to also use the flag `-s`

```
"start": "sirv public -s --no-clear"
```

This will start sirv in *spa mode* and will redirect all unknown routes to index.html.

You are right to suspect this will not work in production either, for the exact same reasons.  There you also have to add a redirect, how this is done depends on where you host, the documentation for most popular hosts has this information, if you cannot find, *open a new question here* as it would no longer be svelte related.

Comment: Thank you @Stephane, it works, but will this work even after i finally host my /build folder  (static html, css and js files) into a webhost like GitHub pages ?

Comment: @RamyHadid I don't know how to setup Github, for this but this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296012/is-there-a-configuration-in-github-pages-that-allows-you-to-redirect-everything thread seems to suggest to make a 404 page that is exactly the same as the index.  As always check dates to see if the answer is not outdated